# When migrating database from Magento to localhost I get a timeout error

Tags: database, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.7

I have a Magento website with a 4.33 GB database. I need to manipulate some of the data so I exported the database, then zip it but when I try to import it inside phpmyadmin on localhost I get timeout error and only 1/3 of the tables get transferred. I have edited the my.ini as well as php.ini and made the execution time 6000 but the issue is not from there. I believe it should be something with Magento that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your database using command line.

```
shell> mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
```

You can load the dump file back into the server like this:

**UNIX**

```
shell> mysql db_name < backup-file.sql
```

The same in **Windows** command prompt:

```
mysql -p -u [user] [database] < backup-file.sql
```

**PowerShell**

```
C:\> cmd.exe /c "mysql -u root -p db_name < backup-file.sql"
```

**MySQL command line**

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```